# Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled but my CPU tempature is just fine

Tags: cpu, temperature, dmesg

The tempature of my CPUs are just fine, there is no problem and the CPU usage for each CPU is usually under %10. But when I check dmesg, I usually see CPU errors about tempature above threshold but it's not true. How can i fix this problem?

```
[   39.387155] CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.387157] CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.387158] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.387160] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.387161] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.387163] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.387164] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.387165] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.387168] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.387176] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[   39.388157] CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[   39.388158] CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
[   39.388159] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[   39.388160] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[   39.388161] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[   39.388162] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[   39.388163] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[   39.388164] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[   39.388165] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[   39.388167] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
```

Comment: What is the normal temp of your CPU's? What utility are you using to see this?

Comment: I used dmesg to see the log attached to this post. I used system monitor to check the CPU usage. Other than that I checked my laptop and it's tempature was average. The fans were working just well. There was nothing abnomal but I still get this error.

Comment: Do you have thermald installed? Check with `dpkg -l thermald`. Or tlp `dpkg -l *tlp*`. These are not errors, but rather, some utility checking the CPU temps and then throttling back the CPU performance to reduce temperature.